# Is there better way to do Angular component inheritance with inheriting template

Tags: angular, typescript, inheritance

I have Angular project with thousands of forms. These forms are all the same, they have almost the same way functioning but there is some differences between these forms in functionally part and in template part.

I need some better way of inheriting components, something like where I can define the base component with his functionality and his template, but in that template I can set some ng-template elements which I will change in child component of this parent.

I found way of doing this with extending base component and in template of child component adding parent element and with nested content changing the way of parent component. Code is on SandBox (https://codesandbox.io/s/github/dsavke/inheratance-test), this is just dummy example of this situation.

BaseFormComponent code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'base-form',
    templateUrl: './base-form.component.html'
})
export class BaseFormComponent {
    private counter: number = 0;

    @ContentChild('content') content!: TemplateRef<any>;

    public editUrl: string = '';

    public onEdit(): void {
        //some logic
    }

    public onSave(): string {
        if (!this.canSave())
            return 'Not saved';

        return 'Saved';
    }

    public canSave(): boolean {
        return true || true;
    }

    private updateCounter(): void {
        this.counter++;
    }
}
```

BaseFormComponent template code:

```
<h2>Base component</h2>
<p>Can save form? {{canSave()}}</p>

<ng-container
    style="border: 1px solid red;"
    *ngIf="content"
    [ngTemplateOutlet]="content"
></ng-container>
```

UserFormComponent ts code:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'user-form',
    templateUrl: './user-form.component.html'
})
export class UserFormComponent extends BaseFormComponent {
    public override canSave(): boolean {
        return false;
    }
}
```

UserFormComponent template code:

```
<base-form>

    <ng-template #content>

        <h5>This is from USER FORM!</h5>

    </ng-template>

</base-form>
```

This is the only way I have found component inheritance to work in Angular, but there is several problems:

1. **In this situation I am duplicating instances of BaseFormComponent, one is created when I have extended mine UserFormComponent and the other one is created in template where I put element of BaseFormComponent so I could get the UI of that component**;
2. **Overriding methods in UserFormComponent here is useless because instance of parent (mine extended component) is never visible (because of decorators, but I need to have two templates, one for base component who will showed and the other one for my component which I will change some structure using ng-template), it just show an instance from template**;

**Is there some other way to do inhertance**, but I need **template and functionallity from parent component** and I also need **template and functionallity in child component**, something like you get the all template from parent component, but you can change these elements in some way in child component, and this would be a real inheritance, is that even possible in Angular?

**EDIT:**
This form is used on 1000+ places, it's kind a big form, it has like 10+ child components, and UI of this form you can change with a parameters, it's like generic form but mostly you will always use all features from this form. There is also form inputs and that will need be passed through content projection or some new way of inheritance with template, this part cannot be generated, because you will always need to change this.

Comment: is `ng-content` what you want?

Comment: @YeXiaoRain I need some way of presenting inheritance, ng-content is one of these, in my example here ng-container is used, but they are functioning on similar way, but in this example problem is with inheritance, when you need to override some method, method which you will reuse in many places.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but it might put you on the right path.

### Description

I essentially did something very similar for a shared-form-wizard component a while back. In my instance, I wanted to create a `shared-wizard.component` that standardized a form dialog, but allowed me to project the individual tabs that I wanted within that Shared Wizard. This way I could re-use that base component for different Wizards throughout my application.

In my case, I did not use actual inheritance as I separated out my logic so that I wouldn't have to worry about it, but I don't imagine it would cause you too much additional trouble.

### Code Examples

Create Custom ContentProjectorTemplateRef directive & pipe. This will allow us to project our custom content. In my instance, I use it to iterate tab content, which is why I use index in the pipe, but you can remove if it necessary.

```
@Directive({
  selector: "[contentProjectorTemplateRef]",
  standalone: true,
})
export class ContentProjectorTemplateRefDirective {
  constructor(public templateRef: TemplateRef<unknown>) {}
}

...

@Pipe({ name: "contentProjectorTemplateRef", standalone: true })
export class ContentProjectorTemplateRefPipe implements PipeTransform {
  public transform(content: QueryList<ContentProjectorTemplateRefDirective>, index: number): TemplateRef<unknown> {
    return content.get(index)?.templateRef;
  }
}
```

In your base component define a query list for the content you wish to project.

```
@ContentChildren(ContentProjectorTemplateRefDirective) content!: QueryList<ContentProjectorTemplateRefDirective>;
```

Then add the ngTemplateOutlet to the base-component interface:

```
<!-- Project the templateRef into the templateOutlet -->
<ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="content | contentProjectorTemplateRef : i">
</ng-container>
```

Then wrap all of it in  elements, and pass that along to base-component, along with any other configuration inputs you might need. This is essentially what it looks like at the end of things:

**base.component.html**

```
<form #sharedForm="ngForm">
  <h1>Shared Form</h1>
  <mat-tab-group
    (focusChange)="onTabChange($event)"
    [(selectedIndex)]="selectedTabIndex"
    animationDuration="0ms"
    mat-align-tabs="start"
    preserveContent="true"
  >
    <mat-tab
      *ngFor="let tab of configuration.tabs; let i = index"
      [aria-label]="tab.label"
      [disabled]="tabShouldBeDisabled(tab, i)"
    >
      <!-- ng-template allows us to lazy-load this with custom content -->
      <ng-template mat-tab-label>
        <span> {{ tab.label }} </span>
      </ng-template>

      <!-- Project the templateRef into the templateOutlet -->
      <ng-container
        *ngTemplateOutlet="content | contentProjectorTemplateRef : i"
        matTabContent
      ></ng-container>
    </mat-tab>
  </mat-tab-group>
...
</form>
```

**base.component.ts**

```
export class SharedWizardComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy {
  @ContentChildren(ContentProjectorTemplateRefDirective)
  content!: QueryList<ContentProjectorTemplateRefDirective>;

  @ViewChild("sharedForm", { static: false }) public sharedForm: NgForm;
  @Input() form: UntypedFormGroup;
...

  // Allows you to use the custom-form from child-changes in the parent.
  public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
          this.sharedForm = this.form as unknown as NgForm;
    }
  }
```

Then in the child:

**child-form-1.component.html**

```
<form #childForm="ngForm">
  <shared-wizard>
    <ng-template contentProjectorTemplateRef> ...customContent1 </ng-template>
    <ng-template contentProjectorTemplateRef> ...customContent2 </ng-template>
    <ng-template contentProjectorTemplateRef> ...customContent3 </ng-template>
  </shared-wizard>
</form>
```

Then you're pretty much good to go. Obviously, you'll have to hook some additional stuff regarding the forms, but this will allow you to separate your logic better, without having to do true inheritance if you don't want to, but allow you the flexibility to change the parent component from your child component.

Comment: this solution is okay for tabs and handling way of them, but in this way you loose possibility of overriding some methods and using the same model of forms through your whole app.

Comment: How about leveraging DI via useFactory(),useClass() etc...for "overriding" that logic

Comment: @savke I'm not sure what you mean by losing the possibility of using the same model of forms. Overriding the functions, yes, but that can simply be solved by adding in logic into the base function that checks for a configuration function, which you would then call from the base component. This would not be true "overrides", but would perform as such. Given your other constraints, I think this is the only way to solve it in a manner that is close to what you want to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Really I don't know how many parts share all your forms, so I don't know if this answer can help you, but I suggest another approach: content projection.

Imagine you have a BaseFormComponent

```
<fieldset class="container">
  <legend>{{title}}</legend>
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div>
    <button (click)="submit(form)">submit</button>
    <button type="button" (click)="cancel()">cancel</button>
  </div>
  <div>{{result$|async}}</div>
</fieldset>
```

See that you can add code to your baseForm component

```
  @Input('formGroup') form: FormGroup;
  @Input('title') title: string = '';
  @Input('dataService') dataService:any=null

  result$:any
  constructor(private router: Router, private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}
  cancel() {
    if (this.form.touched && window.confirm('Do you really want to leave?')) {
      this.router.navigate(['../'], { relativeTo: this.activatedRoute });
      this.form.reset();
    }
  }
  submit(form) {
    if (form.valid) {
      this.result$=this.dataService.save(form.value).pipe(
                      map((res:any)=>res.success?'Data save':'error'))
    } else form.markAllAsTouched();
  }
```

Then you form components can be like,e.g.

```
<base-form [formGroup]="form" title='Users' [dataService]="userService" >
  <label>User name :</label><input formControlName="userName">
  <label>Password :</label><input formControlName="password">
</base-form>
```

Where even you can get the BaseComponent to override the functions if was necessary or give value to variables "not input"

```
  @ViewChild(BaseFormComponent,{static:true}) base:BaseFormComponent
  constructor(public userService:UserService) {
  }
  form: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
    userName: new FormControl(''),
    password: new FormControl(''),
  });
  ngOnInit()
  {
    this.base.title='users'
    this.base.actionButton="create user"
  }
```

A [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-a811at?file=src%2Fforms.module.ts)

Comment: This is also some solution for this problem. I have tried accomplishing things in this way but I kind feel that with this solution there is more problems than doing inheritance and trying to find some way of content projecting. In this way you loose inherating options and all structure that comes with inheritance.